# typescript-eslint: how to lint React props to newlines

Tags: reactjs, eslint, prettier, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to add a linting rule that breaks long `React` property values into new lines. The example below shows that the property `paragraph` is super long, and I don't know how to lint it to make it break to new lines.

```
<Card
  header="General Contractors, Engineering Procurement Providers, Prime Contractors"
  id="gen-contractor"
  paragraph={`Construction companies that build pipelines. While these companies may provide many services "in-house", they often sub-contract work that requires special equipment or
know-how`}
  onCardToggle={(isChecked) => console.log('isChecked', isChecked)}
/>
```

Here is my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb-typescript"],
  "env": {
    "jest": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": "tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin"],
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": "off",
    "react/jsx-one-expression-per-line": 0,
    "react/prop-types": 0,
    "react/require-default-props": "off",
    "react/destructuring-assignment": 0,
    "react/static-property-placement": 0,
    "jsx-a11y/alt-text": 0,
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { "devDependencies": true }],
    "object-curly-newline": "off",
    "operator-linebreak": [
      "error",
      "before",
      { "overrides": { "=": "after" } }
    ],
    "implicit-arrow-linebreak": 0,
    "no-confusing-arrow": 0
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["node_modules/", ".next/", ".eslintrc.json"]
}
```

Here is my `.prettierrc`:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "all"
}
```

Here are all the linting related dependencies inside of my `devDependencies`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.21.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.21.0",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The universal answer to questions like "How can I make Prettier format my code in such a way that ...?" is "You can't."

Prettier's purpose is to facilitate collaboration in projects and teams by taking care of code style, not to be a customizable code formatter that does whatever the user wants. In other words, the formatting it produces isn't really customizable, and this is intentional. Read more here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html